# Velocity of efflux of water leaking though a hole in a beaker

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In my textbook [Torricelli's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli's_law) gives the velocity of the outflow as:

$$ v = \sqrt{2gh} $$

However, as the water leaks out, won't the container move in the opposite direction? That effect seems to have been ignored here. Or is it assumed that there is friction between beaker and surface and the reaction force of reflux is relatively smaller?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about the usual Torricelli's law experiment that looks like this:

[image: Torricelli experiment]

([image from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:TorricelliLawDiagram.svg))

If so then the velocity is calculated from the requirement that the kinetic energy of the water flowing out must be equal to the potential energy decrease as the water level falls. The calculation normally assumes that the container is fixed and it only calculates the kinetic energy of the water.

You are quite correct that the container will feel a force in the opposite direction, and this force is just the rate of change of momentum of the water i.e. the mass flow rate multiplied by the velocity. Whether the container will move, and how fast it accelerates, will depend on the friction between the container and the surface and the mass of the container + water.